# Get user by _id, delete user by _id, update user by _id in Next.js 14, Typescript, MongoDB

Tags: typescript, mongodb, next.js

I am trying to fix 3 request methods that doesn't work, a GET/UPDATE/DELETE user by _id.

I get a no page found in the API call when I run it in the browser and same in postman.

The route when I call my API is http://localhost:3000/api/users and this get all the users, but when I run http://localhost:3000/api/users/{_id}, replace {_id} with the actual user id I get no page found.

The code below is the 3 requests code:

```
// Function to get user by _id
export async function getUserById(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  try {
    console.log('Route accessed:', req.url); // Log the accessed route

    const { id } = req.query; // Retrieve the _id parameter from the request query

    // Fetch user by _id from UserModel
    const user = await connectAndDisconnect(() => UserModel.findById(id as string));

    if (!user) {
      console.log('User not found:', id);
      return res.status(404).json({ error: 'User not found' });
    }

    // Return the fetched user
    return res.status(200).json(user);
  } 
  catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching user by ID:', req.query.id, error);
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
}

// Function to update user by _id
export async function updateUserById(request: NextRequest) {
  const userId = request.nextUrl.searchParams.get('_id');
  const { body } = request;

  if (!userId) {
    return new NextResponse('Invalid user ID', { status: 400 });
  }

  const updatedUser = await asyncHandler(
    () =>
      connectAndDisconnect(() =>
        UserModel.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, body as Partial<IUser>, { new: true })
      ),
    'Error updating user by ID'
  );

  if (!updatedUser) {
    return new NextResponse('User not found', { status: 404 });
  }

  const jsonUpdatedUser = JSON.stringify(updatedUser);

  return new NextResponse(jsonUpdatedUser, {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  });
}

// Function to delete user by _id
export async function deleteUserById(request: NextRequest) {
  const userId = request.nextUrl.searchParams.get('_id');

  if (!userId) {
    return new NextResponse('Invalid user ID', { status: 400 });
  }

  const deletedUser = await asyncHandler(
    () => connectAndDisconnect(() => UserModel.findByIdAndDelete(userId)),
    'Error deleting user by ID'
  );

  if (!deletedUser) {
    return new NextResponse('User not found', { status: 404 });
  }

  const jsonDeletedUser = JSON.stringify(deletedUser);

  return new NextResponse(jsonDeletedUser, {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  });
}
```

The code below is the route.ts file:

```
// api/users.ts
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { createUser, getAllUsers, getUserById, updateUserById, deleteUserById } from 
'@/app/controllers/user';
import handleRequest from '@/app/middleware/handlerequest';

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  return handleRequest(request, {
    //Get all users works
    '/api/users': getAllUsers,
    '/api/users/:id': getUserById,
  });
}

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  return handleRequest(request, {
    //Create new user works
    '/api/users': createUser,
  });
}

 export async function PUT(request: NextRequest) {
   return handleRequest(request, {
     '/api/users/:id': updateUserById,
   });
 }

 export async function DELETE(request: NextRequest) {
   return handleRequest(request, {
     '/api/users/:id': deleteUserById,
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way the projet is structured seems off to me. It kinda matches the Pages router way (`api/users.ts`) but you export methods (`GET|POST|etc`) instead of a unique handler and you are missing the dynamic part `[[id]]`

With App directory, you should have `app/users/route.ts` and `app/users/[id]/route.ts` and expose methods `GET|POST|etc` the way you do. But that will break your middleware... it is not meant to be used like that

Since you mention Next.js 14, this is probably the way to go (see [route handlers](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers))

```
// app/products/api/users/[id]/route.ts

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  const { searchParams } = new URL(request.url)
  const id = searchParams.get('id')
  const user = await getUserById(id)
 
  return Response.json({ user })
}
```

---

The Pages router (the old way) way matches your structure, but you need to export a single `default` function, and handle methods manually. You also need to change the file name to include the optional `[[id]]` dynamic segment

(see [api routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/api-routes))

```
// pages/api/users/[[id]].ts

export default function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    const { id } = req.query
    if (id) {
      const user = await getUserById(id)
      res.status(200).json({ user })
    } else {
      // Get users list
    }
  } else {
    // Handle any other HTTP method
  }
}
```